# Can i get the `insert_id` (actually just the `id`) when inserting with `ON DUPLICATE KEY`?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I am using `MySQLi` in PHP, and as it turns out, when performing a `INSERT` query (via `MySQLi::query()`) with a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax, the `insert_id` property on the `MySQLi` object does not get updated with the `ID` of the entity if you try to insert something that violates the `UNIQUE` index on the database.

I would really like to avoid a second query, but i haven't been able to find in the documentation if there is any alternative way to reach the ID of the entity whose `UNIQUE` index has been broken (which is essentially the entity i am trying to insert, so i want to be able to tie it to that ID)?

Just to clarify, i am aware i can get the `id` if i want to, with a second (`SELECT`) query, but i am wondering if there is some metadata on the MySQLi object that would allow me to get the `id` of the entity in question, without doing a second query?

Comment: what key you are using to trigger ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: @YourCommonSense sorry i don't really know what you mean by key tbh... if you mean which index, it's a `UNIQUE` index, if you mean which columns, it's a non-primary one, it's a combination of `INT` columns

Comment: there is a real weird trick. add id=last_insert_id(id) to your update query